# If my matrix is $3\times3$, does this refer to an $m\times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a $3\times3$ matrix. I can consider it as an $n\times n$ matrix, but the same as an $m\times n$ matrix, where $m=3$ and $n=3.$

Comment: Yes you can $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Sure! It is an $m \times n$ matrix with $m=n=3$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!